# Uploading a file without a form - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Ruby 2.1
Rails 4.1

It should be pretty simple to upload a file without using any gems. I would include in a form something like this:

```
<% form_for @upload, :multipart => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :uploaded_file %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload file" %>
<% end %>
```

What I want to do is upload the file through a single menu action. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: file_field is a form helper. I am NOT looking to do this through a form but through a menu selection.

Comment: Your comments do not offer any help toward answering my question. The first part of your second comment is exactly what I posted. You may have noticed that to get to the view I posted, you kind of need a link from a menu item. The second part is not suitable for all browsers and I'm looking for the Rails way of doing it.

Comment: "This question does not any research effort, it is unclear or not useful". This is the tip you see when you click on the downgrade arrow. Is what I'm asking so obvious?

Comment: ok, i removed both, sorry for distracting your attention.

Comment: I didn't downgrade your question. But for me is obvious that there is no such thing, that you are searching in Rails. It is not an ordinary convention to upload a file "through a single menu action"

Comment: My bad. I was writing a general note and not responding to you directly. It irks me that people downgrade but are not required to leave a note explaining why they did it. I forgot that a notification will go to the person who commented last.